# iOS: event's eventIdentifier property is nil when trying to save event to calendar

Tags: ios, calendar

I am trying to save a few events to the standard calendar, and then save the eventIdentifier for them so that I can change/erase them later, however, when I try to save the eventIdentifier to an array, the app throws an exception saying that it's nil.
here's my code:

```
int i,j;
for (i=0; i<[self.tableView numberOfSections]; i++){
            for (j=0; j<[self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i]; j++){
                NSString *title =[self getTitleInSection:i forRow:j];
                NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
                [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
                NSDate *myDate = [formatter dateFromString:[self getActionDate:i]];
                EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
                [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                    if (!granted) { return; }
                    EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
                    event.title = title;
                    event.startDate = myDate;
                    event.endDate = [event.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60];  //set 1 hour meeting
                    [event setCalendar:[store defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
                    NSError *err = nil;
                    [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];

                    if (self.parameters.count==7){
                        NSMutableArray *eventIdArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: nil];
                        [self.parameters addObject:eventIdArray];
                    }
                    [[self.parameters objectAtIndex:7] addObject:event.eventIdentifier];  //this is so you can access this event later
                }];
            }
        }
```

and the exception it throws is

2014-08-05 16:23:27.216 fazendoMinhaFesta[2544:e403] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

and highlights the line

```
[[self.parameters objectAtIndex:7] addObject:event.eventIdentifier];
```

saying Thread 9:signal SIGABRT

So I guess either event or event.eventIdentifier is nil, but I can't figure out why.

Is there anything that would cause them to be nil?

( I have checked and myDate and title are the values they're supposed to be)

Comment: The error is clear. You are trying to add a `nil` object to the array. Either `event` or `even.eventIdentifier` is `nil`.

Comment: @maddy I should have made my question clearer. I know one of those is nil, I just have no idea why. That's what I want to find out

Comment: Which one is `nil`? `event` or `event.eventIdentifier`?

Comment: @maddy it started working now. no idea why :p the only thing I did was add a test to find out which was nil haha even after I removed the test it stil works. thanks for your attention :)